# itext7.7.1.1 cannot create PdfDocument from PDFReader

Tags: powershell, itext7

I am in the early stages of moving from iTextSharp to iText7, but am failing early.  This is the code snippet:

```
$lib="C:\bob\pshell\iText7\itext7.7.1.1\lib\net40\itext.kernel.dll"
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($lib)
$reader=  New-Object itext.kernel.pdf.PdfReader   "<valid pdf>"
$PDFdocument = New-Object itext.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument($reader)
```

This produces an error:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot open document."
```

The `$reader` object seems valid, and returns a length and **`IsOpenedWithFullPermission`** returns `$true`.   I have successfully used similar code to create and write to a PDF, but cannot create a PDFDocument from a PDFReader object.  Am I missing something simple?  Thanks

Comment: The error message is quite clear: you are missing an argument in the constructor of the `PdfDocument` class. It's as if you didn't read the documentation. You want to read a document in order to create another document, so where is the `PdfWriter`? You have to pass a `PdfWriter` instance to the constructor of the `PdfDocument`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Bruno.    I did check the declared constructors for PDFDocument, and the first is Void .ctor(iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader), and the documentation at [link](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext7/7.0.1/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/PdfDocument.html) suggests this is the constructor to use to 'Open PDF document in reading mode.'.  In fact, I do only want to read the document so that I can extract the form fields.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Be sure you're also loading the correct version of BouncyCastle.Crypto (1.8.1.0 currently). I had the newer version loaded and it was barfing with the same generic error. Only figured it out by looking at the InnerException.