# itext7: Getting a 'cannot find file' error when attempting to read a PDF document

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext, itext7

I have been trying to solve this all day and I seem to be getting nowhere.

I am trying to use [itext7-dotnet](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet) to read a pdf document. All the examples and tutorials that I can find for PowerShell are using an older version of this library called "itextsharp". I have not been able to find any example or tutorials that use the itext7 or newer.

I did find some examples but they are all using advanced csharp code, like this question, [Parsing/Reading a PDF Document using iText7 C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63498815/parsing-reading-a-pdf-document-using-itext7-c-sharp). I dont know any csharp.

I was able to find the official **.NET** documentation for itext7 (in csharp), it looks like I need to use[`iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader`](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/8.0.1/classi_text_1_1_kernel_1_1_pdf_1_1_pdf_reader.html#a14bae86575e9cc95ed2c65ef102fb3c3), which has methods like `PdfReader()`, the documentation does not have code examples.

but I am confident I can figure it out, following the docs anyways. If I can just figure out how to load the itext7 library correctly.

For example, I tried to follow [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49294124/itext7-7-1-1-cannot-create-pdfdocument-from-pdfreader) question on how to load the library:

```
$lib    = "C:\Temp\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.kernel.dll"         
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($lib)       
$testDoc = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:\Temp\sample.pdf")
```

For a brief moment it looks like it works:

```
GAC    Version        Location
---    -------        --------
False  v4.0.30319     C:\Temp\lib\netstandard2.0\itext.kernel.dll
```

But I get this error, other attempts keep giving me the same error:

```
MethodInvocationException:
Line |
   3 |  $testDoc = [iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader]::new("C:\Temp\sample.pdf")
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'itext.commons, Version=8.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

Have a correctly loaded the library and the issues is my PDF file? I tried using other PDF files but the error wont go away. If its the library, how can I correctly load this library?

I got the library, from the official itext7-dotnet (linked above) release page, [THIS](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/releases/tag/8.0.2). The `sample.pdf` is a single page pdf file with a single text box that reads 'Hello World'.

I am on Windows 11 and PowerShell 7.3

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to load the other dependencies as well:

```
itext.kernel.dll
itext.commons.dll
itext.io.dll
itext.kernel.xml.dll
```

From
https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/releases

Comment: Hey thanks allot for this kind answer. Sure enough that was what I wass missing. after also downloaing and adding `commons.dll` it worked. now `$testDoc` returns an object with the name `iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfReader`.  Now to find out what to do with that object.  By the way I was not able to find `itext.kernel.xml.dll` under the link you linked to, do you know where I may be able to find it?

Comment: The xml functionality should be included in the parent itext.kernel.dll, so no need to include that one.